# Convert a #define'd char* to enum value

Tags: c++

In a header that I can't edit, I have the following defines:

```
#define ENUM_SOMETHING_A "A"
#define ENUM_SOMETHING_B "B"
#define ENUM_SOMETHING_C "C"
```

I would like to wrap these in an enum, something similar to:

```
enum Something {
    A = ENUM_SOMETHING_A,
    B = ENUM_SOMETHING_B,
    C = ENUM_SOMETHING_C
};
```

Where Something::A is the decimal ASCII value of ENUM_SOMETHING_A, and so on.

I've tried several approaches to this, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is it possible, and if so, how can I accomplish it? Again, the #defines cannot be changed.

I tried casting, and I tried ENUM_SOMETHING_A[0], but neither worked. Also - this is not C++0x.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible unless you're using C++0x.
Maybe use a class?

Comment: How far throughout the code base are they spread?  You could always bite the bullet and just change the type where ever they're used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enum values cannot be strings, so using an enum isn't really appropriate here, unless you want to add an additional mechanism to map the enum values to their string counterparts.  However, you could do something like this:

```
// Header
typedef char const * Something_value;

namespace Something
{
    Something_value const A;
    Something_value const B;
    Something_value const C;
}
```

---

```
// Implementation
namespace Something
{
    Something_value const A = ENUM_SOMETHING_A;
    Something_value const B = ENUM_SOMETHING_B;
    Something_value const C = ENUM_SOMETHING_C;
}
```

Comment: Should have been more clear - they are strings, but strings of length exactly one. I like your style above though, so I will just use that - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  An `enum` must be defined using integer constants.  A `char*` is by definition not an integer constant.

The best you can do is to map your constants to the equivalent `char` value (which you may adjust arithmetically to your liking):

```
#define MY_ENUM_SOMETHING_A (ENUM_SOMETHING_A[0]) /* 65 */
#define MY_ENUM_SOMETHING_B (ENUM_SOMETHING_B[0]) /* 66 */
#define MY_ENUM_SOMETHING_C (ENUM_SOMETHING_C[0]) /* 67 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this within the language.  You *can*, however, write a shell script that generates the enum you want from the header you can't edit.  It would look something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
# usage: define2enum input output

set -e
exec > "$2"
echo 'enum Something {'
sed -ne 's/^#define ENUM_SOMETHING_\([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*\) "\(.\)"$/    \1 = '\''\2'\'',/p' < "$1"
echo '};'
```